# Llenar combo dinámicamente en C# desde columna de SQL

Tags: c#, sql

tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ObtenerAplica]   
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT id_aplica, desc_aplica, Opc_Orden FROM aplicatipotienda ORDER BY Opc_Orden  ASC  
END
```

Este procedimiento es para llenar un combo en C# el cual es llenado aquí

```
 private void LlenarComboAplicaEn()
        {
            cboAplicaEn.DataSource = null;
            clsDatos oDatos = new clsDatos();
            DataTable MyData = new DataTable();

            if (oDatos.ObtenerAplicaEn(ref MyData))
            {
                if (MyData.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dt in MyData.Rows)
                    {
                        itemAplicaEn.Add(new ComboboxItem(
                            dt["id_aplica"].ToString(), " " + dt["desc_aplica"].ToString()));
                        );
                    } 
                    cboAplicaEn.DataSource = itemAplicaEn;
                    cboAplicaEn.ValueMember = "numItem";
                    cboAplicaEn.DisplayMember = "descItem";
                    cboAplicaEn.SelectedIndex = -1;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                General.msjError("Ocurrio un error al obtener los datos de aplica en");
            }
        }
```

Funciona correctamente, pero el problema que tengo que realizar es que al iniciar la pantalla tenga cargada por default un valor de la tabla en el combo, mi intento fue simplemente colocar el index de ese valor en SelectedIndex pero me regresaron el ejercicio pidiendome cargar ese dato de la base de datos pero no estaticamente, si no dinamicamente, ya que de la manera que lo hice si cambian los valores de index se moveria, pero no entiendo como puedo traerlo por SQL de esa manera, alguien podria ayudarme a comprender como hacerlo?.
Si sirve de algo esta es la tabla en SQL

```
id_aplica desc_aplica       opc_orden
 7           Dato1              0
 1           Dato2              1
 5           Dato3              2
 0           Dato4              3
```

El dato que debo cargar en el combo es el dato2, pensé en intercambiar el valor de opc_orden de Dato1 y Dato2 para mostrarlos simplemente en orden ascendente y así lo cargaría ya, pero si cambio este valor puede afectar a otros procedimientos o funciones del sistema. No se si se pueda realizar desde C# o en SQL alguna función que desconozca

Comment: Solo se me ocurre que en la base datos tengas un campo que fuera algo como "valor predeterminado" o algo así, y entonces, cada vez que cargas el combobox lees también ese valor, y se lo asignas a SelectedIndex.